# Custom Wordpress user which was created directly through SQL does not work for Wordpress login

Tags: sql, wordpress, authentication, passwords, customization

I used the following code to hash the password:

```
$password = $_POST['user_pass'];
$hash = wp_hash_password('$password');
```

What am I missing? The error I get is

> ERROR: The password you entered for the username **willshatner** is incorrect.

Comment: I don't see the hashing?

Comment: sorry fixed              ___

Comment: don't use '$password', use "$password" or just $password

Comment: does it make a difference? it still sends the password to the database encrypted successfully.

Comment: yes it makes a difference, you cannot add variables inside single quote strings the way you can with double quote strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will not input the password you have sent, because of the single quotes:

```
$hash = wp_hash_password('$password'); // here the password is set to the string $password
```

use this code instead:

```
$hash = wp_hash_password($password); // here the password is set to the value of the variable $password
```

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhh....... just one question, how come the encrypted password is different for all of them? i made several users and the encrypted passwords are all different in the database.

Comment: the function doesn't just encrypt with md5 8 times, but it also adds a salt: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password

Comment: By the way, THIS WORKED! =D

Answer (score -1):

Since the password is MD5 encrypted, you'd prob have to encrypt the POST to match the db

```
      $password = MD5($_POST['user_pass']);
```

Comment: isn't that what `wp_hash_password` does?

Comment: What happens when you print_r the $hash?

Comment: that was not the problem. the problem is fixed. the other guy solved it. needed to remove  '' quotes

Comment: this is incorrect, since the hash function does the hashing, and it does it differently: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password